# How to create loop for array which stores objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

So, I have an array with multiple objects.

```
var profile = [
    {"MODE":"Comfort","MONDAY":"09:00:00","TUESDAY":"09:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"09:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"09:00:00","FRIDAY":"09:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Eco","MONDAY":"22:00:00","TUESDAY":"22:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"22:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"22:00:00","FRIDAY":"22:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"07:30:00","TUESDAY":"07:30:00","WEDNESDAY":"07:30:00",
    "THURSDAY":"07:30:00","FRIDAY":"07:30:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"21:00:00","TUESDAY":"21:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"21:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"21:00:00","FRIDAY":"21:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null}
    ];
```

There is a MODE  property, and a week days properties.

What I want, is to store all MONDAY values in array called MONDAY,all TUESDAY values in array called TUESDAY, and etc. Key of that value must be value of MODE(comfort, eco, etc).
So that is the goal:

```
var MONDAY =  ["Comfort":"09:00:00","ECO":"22:00:00", ...]
var TUESDAY = ["Comfort":"09:00:00","ECO":"22:00:00",...]
```

I've tried to filter initial array

```
var comfort = profile.filter(p => p.MODE == "Comfort");
var eco = profile.filter(p => p.MODE == "Eco");
var standby = profile.filter(p => p.MODE == "Standby");



var comfortMode = comfort[0];
var ecoMode = eco[0];
var standbyMode0 = standby[0];
var standbyMode1 = standby[1];



console.log(ecoMode["MONDAY"]);
console.log(standbyMode0["MONDAY"]);
```

But I've got stuck at that point.Seems that I need to hard code values,  and write by hand

```
    var MONDAY = [ecoMode["MONDAY"],comfortMode["MONDAY"],standbyMode0["MONDAY"],standbyMode1["MONDAY"]];
var TUESDAY  = [...,...,...,...]
```

Is there any way to create loop for comfortMode,ecoMode, and other arrays  that every value with key MONDAY were stored in an array called MONDAY?

Comment: I see no loops in your code, only variables and console outputs. Why don't you try creating a loop yourself first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem. The only difference is that in the final output you will not be:

```js
var MONDAY =  ["Comfort":"09:00:00","ECO":"22:00:00", ...]
var TUESDAY = ["Comfort":"09:00:00","ECO":"22:00:00",...]
```

It will be an object with weekdays as keys.

```js
{
  "MONDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Eco": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "07:30:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "21:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "TUESDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Eco": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "07:30:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "21:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "WEDNESDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Eco": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "07:30:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "21:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "THURSDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Eco": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "07:30:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "21:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "FRIDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": "09:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Eco": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "07:30:00"
    },
    {
      "Standby": "21:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "SATURDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": null
    },
    {
      "Eco": null
    },
    {
      "Standby": null
    },
    {
      "Standby": null
    }
  ],
  "SUNDAY": [
    {
      "Comfort": null
    },
    {
      "Eco": null
    },
    {
      "Standby": null
    },
    {
      "Standby": null
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
var profile = [
    {"MODE":"Comfort","MONDAY":"09:00:00","TUESDAY":"09:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"09:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"09:00:00","FRIDAY":"09:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Eco","MONDAY":"22:00:00","TUESDAY":"22:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"22:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"22:00:00","FRIDAY":"22:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"07:30:00","TUESDAY":"07:30:00","WEDNESDAY":"07:30:00",
    "THURSDAY":"07:30:00","FRIDAY":"07:30:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"21:00:00","TUESDAY":"21:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"21:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"21:00:00","FRIDAY":"21:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null}
    ];

var weekdays = ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"];

var finalResult = weekdays.reduce((acc, currentDay) => {
    var dayValues = profile.reduce((acc1, currentProfile) => {
        return [...acc1, {
            [currentProfile.MODE]: currentProfile[currentDay]
        }]
    }, []);

    return {
        ...acc,
        [currentDay]: dayValues,
    };
}, {});

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution you can use. It's not the prettiest but it works and can get you started

```js
var profile = [
    {"MODE":"Comfort","MONDAY":"09:00:00","TUESDAY":"09:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"09:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"09:00:00","FRIDAY":"09:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Eco","MONDAY":"22:00:00","TUESDAY":"22:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"22:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"22:00:00","FRIDAY":"22:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"07:30:00","TUESDAY":"07:30:00","WEDNESDAY":"07:30:00",
    "THURSDAY":"07:30:00","FRIDAY":"07:30:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"21:00:00","TUESDAY":"21:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"21:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"21:00:00","FRIDAY":"21:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null}
    ];

    let monday = []
    let tuesday = []
    let wednesday = []
    let thursday = []
    let friday = []
    let saturday = []
    let sunday = []
    profile.forEach(e => {
        let mode = e.MODE
        let mondayVal = e.MONDAY
        let tuesdayVal = e.TUESDAY
        let wednesdayVal = e.WEDNESDAY
        let thursdayVal = e.THURSDAY
        let fridayVal = e.FRIDAY
        let saturdayVal = e.SATURDAY
        let sundayVal = e.SUNDAY
        monday.push({[mode]: mondayVal})
        tuesday.push({[mode]: tuesdayVal})
        wednesday.push({[mode]: wednesdayVal})
        thursday.push({[mode]: thursdayVal})
        friday.push({[mode]: fridayVal})
        saturday.push({[mode]: saturdayVal})
        sunday.push({[mode]: sundayVal})
    })

console.log("Monday: ", monday)
console.log("Tuesday: ", tuesday)
console.log("Wednesday: ", wednesday)
console.log("Thursday: ", thursday)
console.log("Friday: ", friday)
console.log("Saturday: ", saturday)
console.log("Sunday: ", sunday)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to get one array of hours for each day

```js
let profile = [
    {"MODE":"Comfort","MONDAY":"09:00:00","TUESDAY":"09:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"09:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"09:00:00","FRIDAY":"09:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Eco","MONDAY":"22:00:00","TUESDAY":"22:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"22:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"22:00:00","FRIDAY":"22:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"07:30:00","TUESDAY":"07:30:00","WEDNESDAY":"07:30:00",
    "THURSDAY":"07:30:00","FRIDAY":"07:30:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"21:00:00","TUESDAY":"21:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"21:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"21:00:00","FRIDAY":"21:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null}
];

// declare the object with the resulting arrays
let days = {}

profile.forEach(prof => {
  // we remember the mode for later
  let mode = prof.MODE;
  
  // for .. in loop each attribute of an object
  for (let i in prof) {
    // not needed to save modes
    if (i !== "MODE") {
      // create the array for the day if it doesn't exists 
      if (typeof days[i] === "undefined") {days[i] = [];}
      // add the current value
      days[i].push(prof[i]);
    }
  }
  
})

// show the final object
console.log(days)
```

or this to still have the mode

```js
let profile = [
    {"MODE":"Comfort","MONDAY":"09:00:00","TUESDAY":"09:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"09:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"09:00:00","FRIDAY":"09:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Eco","MONDAY":"22:00:00","TUESDAY":"22:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"22:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"22:00:00","FRIDAY":"22:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"07:30:00","TUESDAY":"07:30:00","WEDNESDAY":"07:30:00",
    "THURSDAY":"07:30:00","FRIDAY":"07:30:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null},
    {"MODE":"Standby","MONDAY":"21:00:00","TUESDAY":"21:00:00","WEDNESDAY":"21:00:00",
    "THURSDAY":"21:00:00","FRIDAY":"21:00:00","SATURDAY":null,"SUNDAY":null}
];
// declare the object with the resulting arrays
let days = {}

profile.forEach(prof => {

  // we remember the mode for later
  let mode = prof.MODE;
  
  // for .. in loop each attribute of an object
  for (let i in prof) {
    // not needed to save modes
    if (i !== "MODE") {
      // create the object for the day if it doesn't exists 
      if (typeof days[i] === "undefined") {days[i] = {};}
      // create the array for the mode if it doesn't exists 
      if (typeof days[i][mode] === "undefined") {days[i][mode] = []}
      
      // add the current value
      days[i][mode].push(prof[i]);
    }
  }
  
})

// show the final object
console.log(days)
```

these two method allow you to grow your initial array without problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items from the input array and aggregate the desired output:

```js
var profile=[{MODE:"Comfort",MONDAY:"09:00:00",TUESDAY:"09:00:00",WEDNESDAY:"09:00:00",THURSDAY:"09:00:00",FRIDAY:"09:00:00",SATURDAY:null,SUNDAY:null},{MODE:"Eco",MONDAY:"22:00:00",TUESDAY:"22:00:00",WEDNESDAY:"22:00:00",THURSDAY:"22:00:00",FRIDAY:"22:00:00",SATURDAY:null,SUNDAY:null},{MODE:"Standby",MONDAY:"07:30:00",TUESDAY:"07:30:00",WEDNESDAY:"07:30:00",THURSDAY:"07:30:00",FRIDAY:"07:30:00",SATURDAY:null,SUNDAY:null},{MODE:"Standby",MONDAY:"21:00:00",TUESDAY:"21:00:00",WEDNESDAY:"21:00:00",THURSDAY:"21:00:00",FRIDAY:"21:00:00",SATURDAY:null,SUNDAY:null}];

var result = profile.reduce((all, el) => {

    Object.keys(el).filter(k => k !== 'MODE').forEach(k => all[k].push({[el.MODE]: el[k]}));

    return all;

}, { MONDAY:[], TUESDAY:[], WEDNESDAY: [], THURSDAY:[], FRIDAY:[], SATURDAY:[], SUNDAY:[] });

console.log(result);
```